# Errors with ZTE modem on Raspbian/RPi2

Tags: raspbian, usb, usb-power, pi-2

I'm having serious trouble getting a ZTE Mf180 USB modem to work on a Raspberry Pi 2 with Raspbian, using pppd to connect.

Usb_modeswitch is working almost flawlessly (sometimes I have to re-plug the dongle after booting the Pi), but after a couple of hours (rarely days), the device "crashes".

Here is what happens (aggregated data from syslog and my applications log):

```
06:00:02 app: pinging some google-server to check connection: ok
06:00:08 app: starting ftp upload (curl) to my server
06:00:26 syslog: option1 ttyUSB2: option_instat_callback: error -71
06:00:48 app: FTP upload (curl) fails with error 6 (can't resolve host)
```

The syslog error floods the syslog starting from that moment. All I can do is unplugging the device. poff/pon does not help; the devices (ttyUSBx) are present.

The Pi is powered with a 1000mA PSU. All that is attached is a EDNET nano WiFi-dongle and the modem.

Any suggestions how to fix/debug that error or shall I just get a Huaweii modem or any UMTS device that is known to work 24/7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously the problem is power related. I supply the modem now with an additional PSU over a Y-cable and it is running for a week now, without any troubles. Possibly another (stronger) PSU for the Pi could solve this as well, for now I'll stay with the additional one.

Hope this helps somebody!